# Equation numbering in North Dakota style

Tags: equations, numbering

I am writing a thesis using the North Dakota University style, but the equation numbers appear as (2..1) for example instead of (2.1). How can I fix that? I am not very experienced in typesetting.

Comment: Where can we find this `style`? Most likely, a `\renewcommand{\thequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}` is sufficient, but without seeing any code, it's a guess only!

Comment: try `\renewcommand\thequation{\thechapter\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It can be found in: file, new, theses, similar to North Dakota State University.

Comment: I assume the university class redefines `\thechapter` to *include* the period. Can you provide a link to the class file together with some minimal example that replicates the problem?

Comment: @Herbert I tried it and now the pdf file is not being generated

Comment: I see that I had a typo in my 1st comment: `\theequation`, not `\thequation` of course...

Comment: @user364961: Now do I have to google for this University? Why not providing the link directly? `File, New, Thesis` looks like a TeXMaker etc. menu command

Comment: @user364961: I'm unable to replicate your results with the [CTAN version of `ndsu-thesis.cls`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ndsu-thesis). The equation number is printed as expected. The University mentions [an older class file](https://www.ndsu.edu/math/resources/tex_and_latex/latex_document_class_for_ndsu_disquisitions/older_latex_document_class_for_ndsu_disquisitions/)... are you perhaps using this older file?

Comment: @user364961: should be: `\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: https://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/Thesis-NDSUThesis.pdf  I was getting a file similar to this one in the link, but now it works! Thank you all for your help

Comment: @user364961: Linking to the thesis - pdf is not really useful ... especially since it does not have a single line of TeX code in it

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry I couldn't link to TeX file. I am using scientific workplace 5.5 I tried the command and my problem is solved now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @user364961: You could have at least tried to reduce it to a MWE ...